# Can there be list in SQL query

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, list, where-clause

My database:-

| script_id | date_time | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:35:00 | 25 | 10 |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:40:00 | 10 | 35 |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:45:00 | 48 | 30 |

Currently I am using below SQL query to fetch the data where 9:40 open < 9:35 open and 9:45 close > 9:35 close and 9:45 open > 9:40 close:

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM data d1 
WHERE d1.date_time = '2019-01-11 09:35:00'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM data d2
    WHERE d2.date_time = '2019-01-11 09:40:00'
      AND d2.script_id = d1.script_id
      AND d2.open < d1.open
      AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM data d3
    WHERE d3.date_time = '2019-01-11 09:45:00'
      AND d3.script_id = d1.script_id
      AND d3.close > d1.close
      AND d3.open > d2.close
  ));
```

So, it gave me result as:

| script_id | date_time | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:35:00 | 25 | 10 |

This is correct result.

How can we execute the same query, like we'll fetch the data of the dates together in DESC order and then executing query as `(open[1] < open[2]) and (close[0] > close[2]) and (open[0] > close[1])` in SQL?

Like instead of `(d2.open < d1.open) AND (d3.close > d1.close) AND (d3.open > d2.close`), can I use `(open[1] < open[2]) and (close[0] > close[2]) and (open[0] > close[1])`? What other changes I need to do in the SQL query.

Comment: the table you shared above. Is it your Table you want to operate on or the required result?

Comment: Add a *clear* example of what your data *is* and the *desired results* together with a clear description of the logic - remember strangers on the internet don't know what you know.

Comment: @Stu I hope the edit have more clearity

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN | NOT IN` operators to check lists for instance

```
Select * from Table WHERE Table.date_time IN (Select dateColumn from Table where dateColumn > '9:35:00')
```

Comment: and how to check the open values then?

Comment: Your question is still a little unclear. do you want to retrieve data from a single table? the table you showed above, is it the result you want or the table you have in db?

Comment: the table i have in the database

Comment: In and Not In is the way to deal with lists in where clause. since your requirements are not clear, I can only help you to some extent. If you want to retrieve data from a single table you can also go with self join

Comment: *SQL query to fetch the data where 9:40 open > 9:35 open* - this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the "next" `open` is less than the one in the current row, use `lead()`:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             LEAD(open) OVER (PARTITION BY script_id ORDER BY date_time) as next-open
      FROM data d
     ) d
WHERE next_open < open
```

Comment: Apologies, I just edited the database and original query in question where there are 3 where clause. Currently looking for list type SQL query

Comment: How can I implement in the query of the question?